# Как изменить переменную в цикле элементов, другим элементом?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В цикле span-ов есть инициализированная переменная 'a' со значением '0'. https://jsfiddle.net/k99yoL10/1 при событии щелчка эта переменная увеличивается на 1. Можно ли сделать так чтобы при нажатии на чёрном span-е обнулить переменную в первом span-е ?

```js
$('span').each(function(){

var a=0; 
$(this).click(function(){ 
alert(a);
a++;
});

});
```

```css
span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:70px;
  height:50px;
  background: red;
}
span:last-of-type{
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

Comment: вам число кликов надо считать для каждого спана отдельно? вы в целом всегда можете писать значения в `data-` атрибуты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вводим число не переменной, а свойством `prop` и при нажатии на `span` обнуляем значение у соседей:

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('a', 0).click(function() {
    var a = $(this).prop('a');
    alert( a );
    // Прибавляем +1 и стираем у соседних
    $(this).prop('a', a + 1).siblings('span').prop('a', 0);
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
span:last-of-type {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```